# Can I split up a nhibernate mapping file?

Tags: nhibernate

Is it possible to split the model into two or more seperate .hbx files?

I'd like to add a class for testing but not have it be in the production code.

Comment: Do you have a subclass?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the class I'm adding would not be a subclass of an existing class. Both classes would implement the same interface though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NHibernate native solution is to adjust `ISessionFactory` configuration. My preferred way would be t move that class mapping `.hbm.xml` files into two different libraries.

The first/common could be `MyProject.Data`, the second, for testing purpose, could be the `MyProject.Test`. The production code would skipp the last element:

#### nhibernate.config

```
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">

  <session-factory name="DefaultFactory">

    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=....</property>
    ...

    <mapping assembly="MyProject.Data" />
    <mapping assembly="MyProject.Test" /> // remove this line for production

  </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

All the mapping files still have to have the suffix `.hbm.xml` and must be marked as *Embedded Resource*

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for but I can't quite get it to work since the mapping in Test needs to reference mappings in Data. Hibernate keeps saying  Association references unmapped class: regardless of the order

Comment: Important is: the `.hbm.xml` files in Test *(in fact in any)* project must be Embedded resources. Check that twice! This is the most suspected. And also: if there is some class mapped in `Data` it cannot be referencing class beeing mapped only in `Test`. Because in production... only `Data` library will be deployed. But there could be some class mapped in Test...referencing the class from Data... because both will be deployed for tests...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I still got it but you can use "extends" in mappings to seperate out classes:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <joined-subclass name="DomesticCat" extends="Cat">
      ...
 </joined-subclass>
```

Cheers !!